# Paste Excel Chart to PPT using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy charts from excel to ppt using the following VBA code. But I am unable to figure out how to copy graphs as charts using the paste special function(Keep source formatting and link data). My code is copying charts as pictures.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyChartToPowerpoint()
    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Dim myPresentation As Object
    Dim mySlide As Object
    Dim myShape As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Open PowerPoint presentation
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Open PowerPoint presentation and set the slide
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\krps\Downloads\In Stock_Support_WSR_12_23_2023_V1.pptx")
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(4)

    ' Copy and paste the first chart
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KSC_Incident_Summary").ChartObjects("Graph1").Chart.CopyPicture
    mySlide.Shapes.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Delete all charts in the slide
    For i = mySlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If mySlide.Shapes(i).Type = msoChart Then
            mySlide.Shapes(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Set chart position
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    With myShape
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 90
        .Width = 800
        .Height = 290
    End With

    ' Set the slide for the second chart
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(4)

    ' Copy and paste the second chart
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("L3 Transfer Trends").ChartObjects("Graph2").Chart.CopyPicture
    mySlide.Shapes.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Set chart position for the second chart
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    With myShape
        .Left = 500
        .Top = 92
        .Width = 287
        .Height = 290
    End With
    
'Slide 7
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(7)

    ' Copy and paste the first chart
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DSR").ChartObjects("Graph3").Chart.CopyPicture
    mySlide.Shapes.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Delete all charts in the slide
    For i = mySlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If mySlide.Shapes(i).Type = msoChart Then
            mySlide.Shapes(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Set chart position
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    With myShape
        .Left = 52
        .Top = 94
        .Width = 530
        .Height = 270
    End With

    ' Set the slide for the second chart
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(7)

    ' Copy and paste the second chart
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("System vs Manual Metrics").ChartObjects("Graph4").Chart.CopyPicture
    mySlide.Shapes.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Set chart position for the second chart
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    With myShape
        .Left = 500
        .Top = 94
        .Width = 270
        .Height = 270
    End With

    ' Activate PowerPoint
    PowerPointApp.Visible = True
    PowerPointApp.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing...

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KSC_Incident_Summary").ChartObjects("Graph1").Chart.CopyPicture
```

with

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KSC_Incident_Summary").ChartObjects("Graph1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
```

And the same thing for your other ones.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is still getting copied as an object in picture format. I am unable to select the data labels within the charts.

Comment: Use the Paste method of the Shapes object, as per your original post.  I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: It is copying as charts but not using the source formatting and is messing up the layout and positions. I want to copy graphs as charts using the paste special function(Keep source formatting and link data).

Comment: I have tested it with `mySlide.Shapes.Paste` and it seems to work fine.  It copies all of the formatting correctly, and it updates the chart when refreshed.